# SQL retornar dados de relacionamento na mesma linha

Tags: sql, sql-server

Ao realizar a consulta

```
SELECT [Product_Id]
      ,[ProductTag_Id]
  FROM [Product_ProductTag_Mapping]
```

Tenho o resultado

[image: Resultado]

Preciso que a Saida seja:

[image: Resultado esperado]

Comment: procure por pivot table, aqui tem algumas respostas sobre isso

Comment: Obrigado Ricardo!

Comment: @RicardoPontual na verdade o `PIVOT` só resolveria se ele quisesse uma coluna por resultado, mas no caso ele só quer concatenar os resultados. Para isso ele deve usar algo como o [`STRING_AGG`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2016).

Comment: hummm mas @Sorack funciona agrupando e concatenando? isso é interessante, vou ver ;)

Comment: @RicardoPontual sim, mas só a partir da versão 2017 do `SQL Server`

Answer (score 0):

A partir da versão 2017 do `SQL Server` você pode usar a função [`STRING_AGG`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2016) que permite agrupar e concatenar resultados:

```
SELECT pptm.product_id,
       STRING_AGG(pptm.producttag_id, ', ') AS producttag_id
  FROM Product_ProductTag_Mapping pptm
 GROUP BY pptm.product_id;
```

Para as versões anteriores você pode criar uma função para concatenar os resultados por `product_id`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_tgs(@product_id INT)
  RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @text NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

  SELECT @text = ISNULL(@text + ',', '') + pptm.producttag_id
    FROM Product_ProductTag_Mapping pptm
   WHERE pptm.product_id = @product_id;

  RETURN @text;
END;
```

E utilizar da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT pptm.product_id,
       fn_tgs(pptm.producttag_id) AS producttag_id
  FROM Product_ProductTag_Mapping pptm
 GROUP BY pptm.product_id;
```

---

> [`STRING_AGG`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2016)
>
> Concatena os valores das expressões de cadeia de caracteres e coloca os valores de separador entre eles. O separador não é adicionado ao final da cadeia de caracteres.